# Power BI Advanced Editor - How to run query if current date is NOT within a list of values?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I want to run a query in Advanced Editor, only if the current date is NOT one of the following - 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25. Otherwise I dont want the query to run.

I have written the below but I am not getting anywhere very fast:

```
let
    Output = if Date.Day (DateTime.LocalNow()) in (1,5,10,15,20,25) then null else 
    let
    Source = PBILifts
in
    #"PBILifts"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Cheers for all help

Edit: So based on suggestion by @Aleksei I tried below but it doesnt work:

```
let
    output= if List.Contains({1,5,10,15,20,25}, Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow())) then #table({},{}) else 
    Source = PBILifts
in
    #"PBILifts"
```

I get the below error:

```
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: The name 'Source' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly
```

Any further help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's PQ, not SQL, so ***in (1,5,...)*** syntax is incorrect. Try something like this (assuming, your query's output is table):

```
= if List.Contains({1,5,10,15,20,25}, Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow())) then #table({},{}) else YourQuery
```

or:

```
let
    output = if List.Contains({1,5,10,15,20,25}, Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow())) then #table({},{}) else PBILifts
in
    output
```

Comment: Hi @Aleksei I have tried this but I get an error, please see main post as I cannot figure out how to add a code block in comments

Comment: Well, I've corrected your query, but it's not only way. For instance, you may add if clause directly to your PBILifts query. Up to you.